# Asynchronous client in Twisted not sending / receiving request (using NetStringReceiver)

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I am trying to do asynchronous programming using Twisted. What I'm trying to do is create a client which will pass query parameters (in my case, hash type and hash value) and wait for the server's response. I am currently using NetstringReceiver for the parameters. However, am having these problems:

1. The client is not able to send its request to the server, and
2. The client hangs forever when I ran it. It seems that there is a callback that's not returning.

Below are the codes for the client and server.
This code is actually based on this [tutorial by Dave Peticolas](http://krondo.com/deferred-all-the-way-down/).

> **Client Code**

```
import os, sys, argparse
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import NetstringReceiver

class QueryProtocol(Protocol):
    response = ''

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.response = data

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.responseReceived(self.response)

    def responseReceived(self, response):
        self.factory.response_finished(response)

class QueryFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = QueryProtocol

    def __init__(self, deferred):
        self.deferred = deferred

    def response_finished(self, response):
        if self.deferred is not None:
            d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
            d.callback(response)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        if self.deferred is not None:
            d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
            d.errback(reason)

class QueryNetProtocol(NetstringReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendRequest(self.factory.hash_type, self.factory.hash_value)

    def sendRequest(self, hash_type, hash_value):
        self.sendString(hash_type + '.' + hash_value)

    def stringReceived(self, s):
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        self.responseReceived(s)

    def responseReceived(self, response):
        self.factory.handleResponse(response)

class QueryNetFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = QueryNetProtocol

    def __init__(self, hash_type, hash_value):
        self.hash_type = hash_type
        self.hash_value = hash_value
        self.deferred = defer.Deferred()

    def handleResponse(self, response):
        d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
        d.callback(response)

    def clientConnectionLost(self, _, reason):
        if self.deferred is not None:
            d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
            d.errback(reason)

    clientConnectionFailed = clientConnectionLost

class QueryProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def query(self, hash_type, hash_value):
        factory = QueryNetFactory(hash_type, hash_value)
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        reactor.connectTCP(self.host, self.port, factory)
        return factory.deferred

def perform_query(host, port):
    d = defer.Deferred()
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    factory = QueryFactory(d)
    reactor.connectTCP(host, port, factory)
    return d

def main(options):
    done = False
    query_result = ""
    host = options.host
    port = int(options.port)
    sha1 = options.sha1
    proxy = QueryProxy(host, port)
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    def process_query_result(response):
        d = proxy.query('sha1', sha1)

        def fail(err):
            print "Problem in processing response : %s" % err
            return response

        return d.addErrback(fail)

    def query_ok(response):
        query_result = response
        done = True

    def query_failed(err):
        print  "Problem in query : %s" % err
        done = True

    def query_done(_):
        if done == True: reactor.stop()

    d = perform_query(host, port)
    d.addCallback(process_query_result)
    d.addCallbacks(query_ok, query_failed)
    d.addBoth(query_done)
    reactor.run()
    print "The result of the query is : %s" % query_result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("host", help="server host/ip")
    parser.add_argument("port", help="server port number to listen to")
    parser.add_argument("-sha1", help="sha1 value to be queried")
    options = parser.parse_args()
    main(options)
```

> **Server Code**

```
import os, sys, argparse
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import NetstringReceiver


class GridQueryService(object):
    def query(self, hash_type, hash_value):
        print "this is the query service. Type is %s and value is %s" % (hash_type, hash_value)
        return hash_value

class GridQueryProtocol(NetstringReceiver):
    def stringReceived(self, request):
        print >>sys.stderr, request
        if '.' not in request: 
            self.transport.loseConnection() 
            return
        hash_type, hash_value = request.split('.')
        self.formRequestReceived(hash_type, hash_value)

    def formRequestReceived(self, hash_type, hash_value):
        found_flag = self.factory.query(hash_type, hash_value)
        if found_flag: self.sendString(str(found_flag))
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class GridQueryFactory(ServerFactory):
    protocol = GridQueryProtocol

    def __init__(self, service):
        self.service = service

    def query(self, hash_type, hash_value):
        return self.service.query(hash_type, hash_value)

def main(options):
    grid_query_service = GridQueryService()
    grid_query_factory = GridQueryFactory(grid_query_service)
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    port = reactor.listenTCP(int(options.port), grid_query_factory, interface=options.host)
    print "Serving GRID query service on %s" % str(port.getHost())
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("host", help="server host/ip")
    parser.add_argument("port", help="server port number to listen to")
    options = parser.parse_args()
    main(options)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server may use netstrings and your client may contain code for using netstrings, but your client *doesn't* use netstrings.

`main` calls `perform_query`.  `perform_query` makes a `QueryFactory` which connects a `QueryProtocol` which never sends any data and doesn't have any logic related to handling netstrings even if it did.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Any suggestions on how to resolve this? Thanks again

Comment: (a) actually send some data (b) send data in the right format (c) interpret responses according to the right format.

Comment: I updated my client code. Able to send data but still,  it hangs during receiving. Can you kindly check? thanks

Comment: It stops at the point where you do `QueryProxy.query` which still doesn't use netstrings.  You fixed `perform_query` to do netstrings, that's progress.  Now fix `QueryProxy.query` to use them, too (or get rid of the two ways to do one thing and use the one you have that works).

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my client. Revised client code is below.
I am now able to send request. Here are the outputs:

```
Sent request! 
String received! 
Handling response! 
I'm called!
Connection lost! - QueryNetFactory
```

As you can see, the callback **process_query_result** callback has been fired. However, the other callbacks were not and I can't still receive the data/result using the QueryFactory/QueryProtocol. I have a suspect that it's about the deferred and callbacks, but I'm quite confused.
In initializing the QueryFactory class, should I really create a new deferred? If yes, how will it realize/know the callbacks added to the original deferred (the one that was returned by the **perform_query** method)? Now if in case I should not create a new deferred, how can I fire the callbacks added in the original deferred in the 'responseReceived' method of the QueryProtocol?

> **Client Code**

```
class QueryProtocol(Protocol):
    response = ''

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "Data received!"
        self.response = data

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "Connection lost!"
        self.responseReceived(self.response)

    def responseReceived(self, response):
        print "Response received!"
        self.factory.response_finished(response)

class QueryFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = QueryProtocol

    def __init__(self):
        self.deferred = defer.Deferred()

    def response_finished(self, response):
        print "Response finished!"
        if self.deferred is not None:
            d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
            d.callback(response)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Client connection failed! - QueryFactory"
        if self.deferred is not None:
            d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
            d.errback(reason)

class QueryNetProtocol(NetstringReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendRequest(self.factory.hash_type, self.factory.hash_value)

    def sendRequest(self, hash_type, hash_value):
        print "Sent request!"
        self.sendString(hash_type + '.' + hash_value)

    def stringReceived(self, s):
        print "String received!"
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        self.responseReceived(s)

    def responseReceived(self, response):
        self.factory.handleResponse(response)

class QueryNetFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = QueryNetProtocol

    def __init__(self, deferred, hash_type, hash_value):
        self.hash_type = hash_type
        self.hash_value = hash_value
        self.deferred = deferred

    def handleResponse(self, response):
        print "Handling response!"
        d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
        d.callback(response)

    def clientConnectionLost(self, _, reason):
        print "Connection lost! - QueryNetFactory"
        if self.deferred is not None:
            d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
            d.errback(reason)

    clientConnectionFailed = clientConnectionLost

class QueryProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def query(self):
        factory = QueryFactory()
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        reactor.connectTCP(self.host, self.port, factory)
        return factory.deferred

def perform_query(host, port, hash_type, hash_value):
    d = defer.Deferred()
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    factory = QueryNetFactory(d, hash_type, hash_value)
    reactor.connectTCP(host, port, factory)
    return d

def main(options):
    done = False
    query_result = ""
    host = options.host
    port = int(options.port)
    sha1 = options.sha1
    proxy = QueryProxy(host, port)
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    def process_query_result(response):
        print "I'm called!"
        d = proxy.query()

        def fail(err):
            print "Process query result failure : %s" % err

        return d.addErrback(fail)

    def query_ok(response):
        print "query ok!"
        query_result = response
        done = True

    def query_failed(err):
        print  "Problem in query : %s" % err
        done = True

    def query_done(_):
        if done == True: reactor.stop()

    d = perform_query(host, port, "sha1", sha1)
    d.addCallback(process_query_result)
    d.addCallbacks(query_ok, query_failed)
    d.addBoth(query_done)
    reactor.run()
    print "The result of the query is : %s" % query_result
```

Again, any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!